# tmap max categories being weirdly combined

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to plot homeless numbers in the UK using tmap. However, I am coming into some problems with the `max.categories` for `tmap_options`.

**Data**

```
EnglandWales <- geojson_read("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/8edafbe3276d4b56aec60991cbddda50_2.geojson", what = "sp")
```

*Homeless data:* 
https://data.cambridgeshireinsight.org.uk/sites/default/files/P1E-national-homelessness-CLG-tab784-to-201718-csv.csv

So I merge the data:

```
EnglandChildDeprivationDataMap<-merge(EnglandMap, 
                                      EnglandHomelessData, 
                      by.x="lad15cd", 
                      by.y="ONS code",
                      no.dups = TRUE)
```

and then I plot using:

```
tm_shape(EnglandChildDeprivationDataMap) +
  tm_polygons("2017/18: Numbers accepted as homeless and in priority need total",
              main.title = "Homelessness Count In The Uk",
              style="cont",
              palette="Purples",
              midpoint=NA,
              title="2017/2018 Recorded Number Of Homeless People") +
  tmap_options(max.categories = 15)
```

From this, I get the warning message:

*"Number of levels of the variable "2017/18: Numbers accepted as homeless and in priority need total" is 199, which is larger than max.categories (which is 15), so levels are combined. Set tmap_options(max.categories = 199) in the layer function to show all levels"*

and my categories get merged like such:
[image]

Why are my categories being merged like this, and how can I make it more understandable?

Comment: this smells like your column is a factor. transform it with as.numeric()!